# Javafx thread join on traffic Light UI. How do I synchronize threads ?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, java.util.concurrent

I have a javafx UI that simulates a traffic light. I have three threads for each of the lights which lights up each of their respective lights while turning off the others. I start the threads and use join() so that each thread can light up their respective lights before another thread starts.

When I use the Thread.join(), the UI freezes but I know the threads are running properly because the of test string i put inside the threads executes and waits for appropriate time before another one executes.

Code is as follows -

main method

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    lightBoard.setArcWidth(10);
    lightBoard.setArcHeight(10);
    lightBoard.setFill(Color.DARKGREY);

    circleGreen.setFill(Color.WHITE);

    circleYellow.setFill(Color.WHITE);

    circleRed.setFill(Color.WHITE);

    Group group = new Group();
    group.getChildren().addAll(lightBoard, circleGreen, circleYellow, circleRed);
    BorderPane light = new BorderPane(group);
    light.setPadding( new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20) );

    GridPane layoutControls = new GridPane();
    layoutControls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Button btnStart = new Button("Start");
    Button btnStop = new Button("Stop");
    layoutControls.add(btnStart, 0, 0);
    layoutControls.add(btnStop, 1, 0);

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setCenter(light);
    root.setBottom(layoutControls);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 380, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Traffic Light Simulator");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    // create and start threads

    Runnable lightGreen = new LightGreen();
    Runnable lightYellow = new LightYellow();
    Runnable lightRed = new LightRed();

    Thread threadGreen = new Thread(lightGreen);
    Thread threadYellow = new Thread(lightYellow);
    Thread threadRed = new Thread(lightRed);

    while(true){
        threadGreen  = new Thread(lightGreen);
        threadGreen.start();
        try{
            threadGreen.join();
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        threadYellow = new Thread(lightYellow);
        threadYellow.start();
        try{
            threadYellow.join();
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        threadRed =  new Thread(lightRed);
        threadRed.start();
        try{
            threadRed.join();
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

thread classes -

```
class LightGreen implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        lock.lock();
        System.out.println("GREEn");
        circleGreen.setFill( Color.GREEN );
        circleYellow.setFill( Color.WHITE );
        circleRed.setFill( Color.WHITE );
        lock.unlock();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }      
    }
}

class LightYellow implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        lock.lock();
        System.out.println("YELLOW");
        circleGreen.setFill( Color.WHITE );
        circleYellow.setFill( Color.YELLOW );
        circleRed.setFill( Color.WHITE );
        lock.unlock();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }

    }
}

class LightRed implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        lock.lock();
        System.out.println("RED");
        circleGreen.setFill( Color.WHITE );
        circleYellow.setFill( Color.WHITE );
        circleRed.setFill( Color.RED );
        lock.unlock();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }    
    }
}
```

How can i resolve this? I have been told Platform.runlater can be used but not sure how to use it. I need to use multithreading for this task.

Comment: You may want add all the code, so that one can try and see whats happening.

Comment: Please do not all **all** code. Better post [mcve]

Comment: Consider using javafx [PauseTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html)  or [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html)

Comment: Im trying to do it using threading. Maybe I should mention it in the post.

Comment: I think your problem is that you never return from start(). getting stuck in that infinite while loop there at the end.  This is going to get complicated - but you could start by pulling the _inside_ of your while into a helper method that you call using Platform.runLater() in start().  Then. at the end of that helper method, you again call it using Platform.runLater.  That emulates your while(true), but moves the execution until later, allowing start() to return, returning control to JavaFX...

Comment: Does each light really need it's own thread? They all sleep for `3000` milliseconds. It'd be easier to use a single repeating task that updates the colors based on the current state. Also, why must you use multithreading for this? School assignment? Again, it'd be easier to use a `PauseTransition` or `Timeline`, like _c0der_ mentioned.

Comment: yes school exercise.  I used different thread because i need to make the time each light stays on a variable to be controlled from UI.

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you _required_, or did you _choose_, to use separate threads as a solution? If you don't _need_ to use threads then the variable light-is-on duration can be accomplished with a `javafx.animation.Timeline`.

Comment: I am required to use different threads.

Comment: @moilejter I tried your method. What was happening before is that the UI was not even being rendered. Now, the UI is displayed. However, once it gets to the first thread, the UI freezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick demo of how to use JavaFx  [PauseTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) to update gui:

```
public class TrafficLight extends Application{

    private static final double RADIUS = 50;
    private static final double PAUSE = 1;
    private Circle  circleRed,  circleYellow,  circleGreen;
    private Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN};
    private int onColor = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        circleRed = new Circle(RADIUS);
        circleRed.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        circleGreen = new Circle(RADIUS);
        circleGreen.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        circleYellow = new Circle(RADIUS);
        circleYellow.setFill(Color.WHITE);

        TilePane light = new TilePane(circleGreen, circleYellow, circleRed);
        light.setPadding( new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20) );
        Scene scene = new Scene(light, RADIUS*8, RADIUS*3);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Traffic Light Simulator");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        update();
    }

    private void update() {

        PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(PAUSE));
        pause.setOnFinished(event ->{
            circleRed.setFill((onColor == 0) ?  colors[onColor] :Color.WHITE );
            circleYellow.setFill((onColor == 1) ? colors[onColor] :Color.WHITE);
            circleGreen.setFill((onColor == 2) ? colors[onColor] :Color.WHITE);
            onColor = ((onColor +1) >= colors.length) ? 0 : onColor+1;

            pause.play();
        });

        pause.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Edit** 
If you need to do it with threads, although I think it is not the optimal tool, try this technique:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TrafficLight extends Application{

    private static final double RADIUS = 50;

    private Circle  circleRed,  circleYellow,  circleGreen;
    private Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN};
    private int onColor = 0;
    private static int threadNumber = 0, invokeThreadNumber =0;
    private static final Object myLock = new Object();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        circleRed = new Circle(RADIUS);
        circleRed.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        circleGreen = new Circle(RADIUS);
        circleGreen.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        circleYellow = new Circle(RADIUS);
        circleYellow.setFill(Color.WHITE);

        TilePane light = new TilePane(circleGreen, circleYellow, circleRed);
        light.setPadding( new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20) );
        Scene scene = new Scene(light, RADIUS*8, RADIUS*3);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Traffic Light Simulator");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        control();
    }

    private void control() {
        //invoke 3 synchronized control threads 
        new Thread( new ColorControl()).start();
        new Thread( new ColorControl()).start();
        new Thread( new ColorControl()).start();
    }

    private void update() {
        circleRed.setFill((onColor == 0) ?  colors[onColor] :Color.WHITE );
        circleYellow.setFill((onColor == 1) ? colors[onColor] :Color.WHITE);
        circleGreen.setFill((onColor == 2) ? colors[onColor] :Color.WHITE);
        onColor = ((onColor +1) >= colors.length) ? 0 : onColor+1;
    }

    class ColorControl implements Runnable {

        private int threadID;
        private static final long PAUSE = 1000;
        private int MAX_THREADS = 3;
        private boolean isStopped = false;

        ColorControl() {
            threadID = threadNumber ++;
        }

        void reset() {
            threadNumber = 0; invokeThreadNumber =0;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (myLock) {

                while (! isStopped  ) {
                    while (threadID != invokeThreadNumber) {
                        try {
                            myLock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                    }
                    //do work here
                    update();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(PAUSE);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}
                    invokeThreadNumber++;
                    myLock.notifyAll();
                    if( invokeThreadNumber >= MAX_THREADS ) {
                        reset();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I need to use multithreading as I am learning about multithreading.

Comment: Thanks this works. I will try to play more with multithreading.